# Proper way to get automatically generated elements by id Angular 2

Tags: angular

I generate 6x6 grid through:

```
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let rowIndex of createRange(6)" [attr.id]="'row-'+rowIndex">
        <ion-col col-2 *ngFor="let colIndex of createRange(6)" [attr.id]="'row-'+rowIndex+'-col-'+colIndex">
          <circle [size]="'100%'" [color]="'lightgray'"></circle>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

createRange() funciton generate just an array of sequentially filled elements like [ 0, 1, 2 ] etc.

`<circle>` is my component but thats no matter

What matter is automatically generated id of each row (e.g. row-1) and each column (e.g. row-1-col-3).

The question is : How should I properly get element by Id in this case ?

I tried to use `#id` and `@ViewChild()` but i dont know to automatically generate #ids

Now I simply use js to this task, e.g. :

```
document.getElementById('row-1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular way to do this would be with a directive in order to avoid using the DOM [**¹**](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html). See [**this plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uhxjMpRAZa3LvPfYFGnn?p=preview) for an **example**.

Long story short pass the local variables `rowIndex` and `colIndex` in to a directive on the circle component

```
<circle 
    customDirective
    [rowIndex]="rowIndex"
    [colIndex]="colIndex"
    [size]="'100%'"
    [color]="'lightgray'"></circle>
```

then as the customDirective:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customDirective]'
})
class CustomDirective {
  @Input() rowIndex: number;
  @Input() colIndex: number;
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```

finally in the ion-grid component class, you will have access to each element through:

```
@ViewChildren(CustomDirective) circles: QueryList;
```

Comment: I tried your sollution but I have problem with changing style of single CustomDirective element. I made a forEach and special condition but I cant get nativeElement and change style or add class.

Comment: Ok i got it through giving public elRef: ElementRef to the directive constructor. All work.